# fastest etag algorithm

Tags: caching, web

We want to make use of http caching on our website - in particular content validation.

Because our CMS constructs pages from smaller fragments of content, the last modified date of the actual page is not always an accurate indicator that the page has changed. Hence we also want to make use of etags. Because page construction is based on lots of other page fragments we think the only real way to provide an accurate etag is by performing some sort of digest on the content stream itself. This seems a little over cooked as caching is supposed to ease the load off the servers but a content digest is obviously CPU intensive.

I'm looking for the fastest algorithm to create a unique etag that is relevant to the content stream (inode etc just is a kludge and wont work). An MD5 hash is obviously going to get the best unique result but is anybody else making use of other algorithms that are faster in a similar situation?

Sorry forgot the important details... Using Java Servlets - running in websphere 6.1 on windows 2003.

I forgot to mention that there are also live database feeds (we're a bank and need to make sure interest rates are up to date) that can also change the content. So figuring out when content has changed can be tricky to determine.

Comment: What platform? What webserver? What language?

Comment: this could be a start point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384811/fastest-hash-algorithm-for-text-data

Comment: Sorry forgot the important details... Using Java Servlets - running in websphere 6.1 on windows 2003.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are also live database feeds (we're a bank and need to make sure interest rates are up to date) that can also change the content. So figuring out when content has changed can be tricky to determine.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a checksum for each fragment, but compute it when the fragment is changed, not when you render the page.

This way, you pay a one-time cost, which should be relatively small, unless we're talking hundreds of changes per second, and there is no additional cost per request.