# Fastest encoding for long texts

Tags: php, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Hash Algorithm for Text Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384811/fastest-hash-algorithm-for-text-data)

For some reason I have to convert some 4-5k chars long texts (in PHP) into an encoded format.
Which encoding type would be the fastest, that supports long texts like this?

Comment: What do you mean with "encoding"?

Comment: Read this. It could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384811/fastest-hash-algorithm-for-text-data

Comment: Fastest encoding function: `f(x) = 0`.  It's O(1).  High hash collision rate though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on PHP.net did some benchmarking with the different hash functions available.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#89574